# Is there any way to have multichannel communication between client and server using socket programming?

Tags: python, sockets

I am writing a client server communication program using python. I have to send a particular message say
'X' after every 5 seconds to server and its value gets incremented(client side). If the value of 'X' exceeds some threshold value I am trying to send some video frames to server. As the video frame size may be large and say it is taking more than 5 seconds for to send complete frames to server than what will happen to my message X? Will it collide with video frames as there is only one communication channel between server and client? And that message X should always reach server every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend sending the video frames and the message X through different ports and using multiprocessing to let them run simultaneously. Here's a link to that explains multiprocessing in a bit more detail: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html.